# ipython notebook as a web tool dev platform

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am planning to port an existing application (or at least part of it where we process data to create graphs interactively) into an ipython based UI. I am wondering if it is possible to create a menu based app using ipython notebook as an engine. Any functionality to create menu-based applications in Ipython? From my experience with Ipython so far, I guess this is not available.

I am thinking of mimicking it by creating html code in markdown cells that will produce menus as select lists, choosing and submitting from there would call some cgi on a server that would update lower parts of the notebook using AJAX. Anyone did similar stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevent you from reusing the component. 
We try to make them as reusable as possible and is should be easy to use our javascript to create your own js frontend. cf @minrk example [here](https://github.com/minrk/singlecell).

If some modification make component more standalone and reusable Patches are welcomed. at some point we might even have each component (codecell, tooltip, completer) installable with bower/component.io/whatever

I would recommend not to add menu through javascript in markdown cell as it will be disable soon.

You might want to have a look at [Exhibitionist](https://github.com/Exhibitionist/Exhibitionist) that uses ipython notebook for some noce stuff.